# VBA: can't change value of text field?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the middle of writing a script that enters details into a sign up form.

The first name field of the form has the following html code:

```
<input name="firstname" class="text-input" id="input-text-view328" aria-describedby="form-input-text-error-view307-required" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="" data-event="blur" data-view-value="" data-stickit-id="stickit_47" autocomplete="off">
```

I can't seem to get the script to enter a value for this field. I have tried each of the following and none seem to work:

```
Set Fname = IE.Document.getElementsByName("firstname")
Fname.Value = "John"

Set Fname = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("text-input")
Fname.Value = "John"

Set Fname = IE.Document.getElementByID("input-text-view328")
Fname.Value = "John"
```

The error i get is

> "run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Since getElementsByName returns collection, you can access them with the index nos

`IE.Document.getElementsByName("firstname")(0).Value = "John"`

OR

```
Set Fname = IE.Document.getElementsByName("firstname")(0)
Fname.Value = "John"
```

OR

`IE.Document.getElementByID("input-text-view328").Value = "John"`

OR

`IE.Document.querySelector("#input-text-view328").Value = "John"`

Comment: hmmm when i do that, i get an error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: both gave me error: "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: Can you share the url

Comment: unfortunately not, as the site is only available if you log into personal acc

Comment: if it helps, here is some more of the html.

<div class="form-element ">
<label class="label" for="input-text-view328">First name <span class="label-optional"></span></label>
<div class="view-firstname" data-view-component="inputtext" data-component-name="firstname" data-directive-processed="true">
<input name="firstname" class="text-input" id="input-text-view328" aria-describedby="form-input-text-error-view307-required" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="" data-event="blur" data-view-value="" data-stickit-id="stickit_47" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

Comment: Are these objects within frame elements? Just guessing, try this `IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementByID("input-text-view328").Value = "John"`

Comment: No, just <div> objects in a <form>

Comment: Try this `msgbox IE.Document.querySelector("#input-text-view328").OuterHTML` Do you get any error or the msgbox ?

Comment: My mistake- it is within an iframe tag

Comment: when i tried the iframe code you sent, i got the "run-time error '42': Object required" error again.

I tried the msgbox code and got the same error there as well, no msg box

Comment: `Set frame = myIE.document.getElementsByName("Enter your frame name")(0)
    Set inp = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByName("firstname")(0)
    inp.Value = "John"`